# Proof of L’Hospital’s Rule

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

When proving the L’Hospital’s Rule. It's usual to see that extending the definition to let $“f(a)=g(a)=0"$. However, I'm trying to prove this by not using this.

Since when $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}  f(x)=0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a} g(x)=0$ and $g'(x)\neq 0$, L’Hospital’s Rule is $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a} \frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}=A\implies \displaystyle\lim_{x \to a} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)}=A$, I suppose $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a} \frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}=A$.

Thus： $0<|x-a|<\delta\implies |\frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}-A|<\epsilon$

Then I pick a interval $[x,x_0] \subset (a-\delta,a+\delta)-\{a\}$. $f,g$. By Cauchy MVT, $\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{g(x)-g(x_0)}=\frac {f'(x_1)}{g'(x_1)}$ for $x_1\in (x,x_0)$

Since $x_1\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)-\{a\}$, it satisfies that $|\frac {f'(x_1)}{g'(x_1)}-A|<\epsilon$

i.e: $|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{g(x)-g(x_0)}-A|<\epsilon \implies$ $|\frac{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-\frac{f(x_0)}{g(x)}} {1-\frac{g(x_0)}{g(x)}}-A|<\epsilon$ when $ 0<|x-a|<\delta$

Since  $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}  f(x)=0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a} g(x)=0$, $0<|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x_0)|<\epsilon^2$ and $0<|x-a|<\delta\implies|g(x)|<\epsilon$. Thus $|\frac{f(x_0)}{g(x)}|<\epsilon\implies \frac{f(x_0)}{g(x)}<\epsilon \iff \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x_0)}{g(x)}=0 $ Similarly: $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x_0)}{g(x)}=0$.

Thus: $0<|x-a|<\delta\implies |\frac{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-\frac{f(x_0)}{g(x)}} {1-\frac{g(x_0)}{g(x)}}-A|=|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-A|<\epsilon.$ (since $0<|x-a|<\delta \iff \lim_{x\to a}$)

This means $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)}=A$